# how to extract .tar file

Tags: ruby, tar

I am trying to extract **.tar** file using the below code, but getting invalid file format error, what is way to extract .tar file in ruby, FYI I am using window OS. I can see the file property as `Tar archive (application/x-tar)`

```
file_path = "/home/logan/skype/bill_2015-12-14.txt.tar"
extract = Gem::Package::TarReader.new(Zlib::GzipReader.open(file_name))
```

**ERROR:**

```
Zlib::GzipFile::Error: not in gzip format
from (irb):68:in `initialize'
from (irb):68:in `open'
```

Comment: Since it is just a tar file, why are you trying to un-gzip the file?

Comment: Shouldn't: `extract = Gem::Package::TarReader.new(file_name)` be sufficient?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sinisterchipmunk/1335041

Comment: Well for one post all your code `file_name` is not defined from what I see, for two you have to tell  `Gem::Package` where to unzip the file, don't give it a file name give it a file path

Comment: @JustinE you have to use `gzip` to unzip it, all `package` does is extract it.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is given on [The Buckblog](https://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2015/7/23/tar-gz-in-ruby.html) and looks like this :

```
require 'rubygems/package'

File.open("chunky_png-1.3.4.gem", "rb") do |file|
  Gem::Package::TarReader.new(file) do |tar|
    tar.each do |entry|
      if entry.file?
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(entry.full_name))
        File.open(entry.full_name, "wb") do |f|
          f.write(entry.read)
        end
        File.chmod(entry.header.mode, entry.full_name)
      end
    end
  end
end
```